# Javascript Regex Conditional

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings like this:

```
#WTK-56491650H #=> want to capture '56491650H'
#M123456       #=> want to capture 'M123456'
```

I want to match everything after the # unless there is a dash then I want everything after the dash. I have a feeling I'm close but maybe not. I've found a lot of stuff about javascript regex conditionals and I can never get it to do the if then else part. It only matches after the # and that's it.

This is what I have so far:

```
/((?=-{1})-(.+)|(?!-{0)#(.+))/
```

And the demo: https://regex101.com/r/bY0yC6/1

Comment: You know what's going to be asked of you, right? I mean you've been on the site long enough to know.... I'll say it anyway: All code relevant to the question must be in the question itself.

Comment: `#(.*-)?(.*)` is the shortest solution I think. Your result is always in group 2.

Comment: @Lux That solution may be short, but it also has the ability to skip to the last `-` in the string. Plus, unused capture groups are useless and take up memory. Always prefer non-capturing groups where possible

Comment: @Lux, you can just use non-capturing group for the first group. `#(?:.*-)?(.*)`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks ... updated post. Forgot to include the regex I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses non-capturing groups `(?:stuff)` which I prefer so I don't have to dig through the result groups to find the string I'm interested in.

```
(?:#)(?:[\w\d]+-)?([\w\d]+)
```

First it throws out the `#` character, then throws out the stuff up to and including the `-` character, if it is there, then groups the rest as your match.

Comment: @slapyo: This is not really correct. `\d` is already included in `\w` and there is no need to use 1st non-capturing group `(?:#)`, just use `#` without any group. See my working answer below which was posted well before this answer. And this regex won't work for `#M123.56` or `#M123:56`

Comment: You're right about the digits being included in that character set. Does that make it incorrect? I don't think so, just redundant. Yours matches any characters besides hyphen and pound, which is arguably less correct depending on the context and potential for other characters. The non capturing group doesn't make it less correct either. Obviously there was something the OP liked more about my answer, maybe because I explained it instead of just pasting a regexp opaquely. Anyway I had upvoted you. Cheers man, have a nice night.

Comment: As OP wrote `I want to match everything after the #` and your regex is using `\w` to match only word characters so obviously there is a disconnect.  Other than this difference of `\w` and `[^-]` I had same regex posted already.

Comment: Okay whatever you say. Better luck next time. I'd recommend making your answer more readable and adding an explanation next time too. Considering the knowledge level of the OP is pretty important, not just posting a "technically correct" answer as fast as possible and then griping when the OP doesn't pick you in the comments

Comment: Explanation was already there in my answer in the first line itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with an optional match to consume everything between `#` and `-`:

```
/#(?:[^-]*-)?([^#-]+)$/mg
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY0yC6/2)

Answer (score 0):

With a single regular expression, your full match will always contain the hash and/or dash because you are using it to define an acceptable string, but the groupings of a match can provide you the information that you're looking for.

you want the string to start with a hash so your regex should contain the `#`

next, you don't want anything before and including a dash `(.*-)?`, and we add a question mark because this is an optional part (ie if there is no dash)

finally, we can grab everything that is left into a final group, which will be your answer `(.*)`

the full expression is then `#(.*-)?(.*)` as pointed out by [Lux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458413/lux)

Comment: for javascript regex, I would also recommend [regexr](http://regexr.com/) as a good testing ground, I am not sure that the link you gave is reporting groups properly